# Method "isNode(:insideFrustumOf:)" always true

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to verify if a specific node is inside the current frustum of the scene.
Therefore I use the method [isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode) from Apple.
I save in every call to [renderer(_:didAdd:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865794-renderer) the corresponding node and later test with isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:).

But the result is always true, which is obviously wrong.

Why can't I test the nodes added by ARKit?

UPDATE:
The asked code, if it helps, great!

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    //...
        nodes.append(node)
    //...
}
```

*nodes* is an array of SCNNodes.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        for node in nodes {
            let result = sceneView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: sceneView.pointOfView!)
            //...
        }
}
```

Here the evaluation of the node takes place. Result always true.

Comment: You will need to post some actual code for us to help you :)

Comment: I did, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted all your code, its hard to provide a 'definitive' answer.

Having said this, I have created an example for you which works perfectly well.

First I created an `[SCNNode]` to store any `SCNNodes` added to the screen:

```
 //Array To Store Any Added Nodes To The Scene Hierachy
 var nodesRendered = [SCNNode]()
```

I then created 3 different `SCNNodes`:

```
/// Creates A Red, Blue & Green SCNNode
func createNodes(){

    //1. Create A Red Sphere
    let redNode = SCNNode()
    let redGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
    redGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    redNode.geometry = redGeometry
    redNode.position = SCNVector3(-1.5, 0, -1.5)
    redNode.name = "RedNode"

    //2. Create A Green Sphere
    let greenNode = SCNNode()
    let greenGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
    greenGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    greenNode.geometry = greenGeometry
    greenNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
    greenNode.name = "GreenNode"

    //3. Create A Blue Sphere
    let blueNode = SCNNode()
    let blueGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
    blueGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    blueNode.geometry = blueGeometry
    blueNode.position = SCNVector3(1.5, 0, -1.5)
    blueNode.name = "BlueNode"

    //4. Add Them To The Hierachy
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(redNode)
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(greenNode)
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(blueNode)

    //5. Store A Reference To The Nodes
    nodesRendered.append(redNode)
    nodesRendered.append(blueNode)
    nodesRendered.append(greenNode)
}
```

Having done this, I then created a function to determine whether these where in the Frustrum of the Camera:

```
/// Detects If A Node Is In View Of The Camera
func detectNodeInFrustrumOfCamera(){

    guard let cameraPointOfView = self.augmentedRealityView.pointOfView else { return }

    for node in nodesRendered{

        if augmentedRealityView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: cameraPointOfView){

            print("\(node.name!) Is In View Of Camera")

        }else{

            print("\(node.name!) Is Not In View Of Camera")
        }
    }

}
```

Finally in the `delegate` callback I called the function like so:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        detectNodeInFrustrumOfCamera()

  }
```

Which yielded results such as:

*RedNode Is Not In View Of Camera*

*BlueNode Is Not In View Of Camera*

*GreenNode Is In View Of Camera*

Hope it points you in the right direction...

Comment: What you are doing is manually adding the SCNNodes to the scene. But my problem was with the added nodes from ARKit. ARKit adds nodes in the callback renderer(_:didAdd:for:) by itself(e.g. for plane detection). So what I understand is that what you did manually, ARKit does by itself, hence it should be possible to track these automatically added SCNNodes as well? But this doesn’t seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue myself while working on an ARKit project. It seems like the function `isNode(node:, insideFrustumOf:)` will always return true for nodes that were automatically added by ARKit.

My workaround was instead of attempting to track the node added by ARKit, create a new node with a clear material that has the same "volume" as your detected object then create a reference and check if that node is inside the point of view.

Add these variables:

```swift
    /// The object that was detected.
    var refObject: ARReferenceObject?

    /// The reference node for the detected object.
    var refNode: SCNNode?

    /// additional node which we'll use to check the POV against.
    var detectionNode: SCNNode?
```

Implement the delegate function `didAdd`:

```swift
public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {


        if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {

            guard let name = objectAnchor.referenceObject.name, name == "my_object" 
            else { return }
            print("detected object for the first time")


            // create geometry
            let cube = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.0)

            // apply transparent material
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.transparency = 0.0
            cube.firstMaterial = material

            // add child node
            let detectionNode = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
            node.addChildNode(detectionNode)

            // store references
            self.detectionNode = detectionNode // this is the reference we really need
            self.refNode = node
            self.refObject = objectAnchor.referenceObject


        }
    }
```

Finally implement this delegate function `updateAtTime`:

```swift
public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        guard let node = self.detectionNode else { return }

        if let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView {
            let isVisible = sceneView.isNode(node, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)
            print("Is node visible: \(isVisible)")
        }
}
```